# Position: sticky; no funciona

Tags: html, css, navbar, position, sticky

Quiero que mi barra de navegación se quede fija en mi archivo web. He probado el position: sticky; top: 0; Pero no funciona, cuando la barra de navegación alcanza el valor top: 0, no se adhiere a la parte superior de la página. El parent no tiene una altura definida, y creo que ese es el problema, pero no sé qué altura le tengo que poner porque el padre es el contenido de la pagina y además no hay ancestors ​​con overflow oculto. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: #FF7F11;
    --secondary-color: #FCD757;
    --default-text: #f5f5f5; 
}
html{
    overflow-x: hidden;
     touch-action: none;
     -ms-touch-action: none;
}
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    touch-action: none;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute;
   padding: 15px 0;
   width: 100%;  
}
h1,p,a,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-family: 'Sawarabi Mincho', serif;
}
.menu{
    font-family: 'Sawarabi Mincho', serif;
}
.vl {
    border-left: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
    height: 30px;
  }
.header__content-area {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 120px;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.header__img-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 114px;
}
.main-logo {
    height: 80px; 
}
.menu__li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 25px;
    font-family: 'Sawarabi Mincho', serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}
.menu__li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu__li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.nav__list {
    padding: 0;
}
.menu__li>a{
    color: var(--default-text);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.menu__li>a:hover {
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
.header__social-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.header__social-nav>div {
    margin: 8px;
    height: 22px;

}
.header__social-nav>div>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--default-text);
}
.media-icon, .mobile-media-icon {
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.media-icon:hover{
    color: var(--primary-color);
    scale: 1.1;
}
.carta-section{
    position: relative;
    height:50vh;
}
.carta-opacity{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:50vh;
    background-color: #0008;
}
.carta-img{ 
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
}
.carta-title{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
/* STICKY NAV BAR ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.sticky-container{
    
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.carta-nav-bar{
    border-top: 3px solid black; border-bottom: 3px solid black; 
    
}
.carta-items-container{
    height: 75px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 120px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.carta-item{
    padding: 20px 40px; 
    background: var(--primary-color);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.carta-item:hover{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.carta-item:focus{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: var(--secondary-color);
}
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.some-content{
    height: 3000px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sticky.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300;400;900&family=Sawarabi+Mincho&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header__content-area">
            <div class="header__img-container"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5c25361496e76fbea2848f55/1553282628515-4T7SHD0BOHGWX7YVNQEM/JP_3_IN_logo.png" alt="" class="main-logo"></div>
            <nav class="header__nav">
                <ul class="nav__list">
                    <li class="menu__li"><a href="index.html">INICIO</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__li"><a href="carta.html">CARTA</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__li"><a href="">MENÚS</a></li>
                    <li class="menu__li"><a href="">CONTACTO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav class="header__social-nav">
                <div><a href=""><svg class="media-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path fill="currentColor" d="M7.8 2h8.4C19.4 2 22 4.6 22 7.8v8.4a5.8 5.8 0 0 1-5.8 5.8H7.8C4.6 22 2 19.4 2 16.2V7.8A5.8 5.8 0 0 1 7.8 2m-.2 2A3.6 3.6 0 0 0 4 7.6v8.8C4 18.39 5.61 20 7.6 20h8.8a3.6 3.6 0 0 0 3.6-3.6V7.6C20 5.61 18.39 4 16.4 4H7.6m9.65 1.5a1.25 1.25 0 0 1 1.25 1.25A1.25 1.25 0 0 1 17.25 8A1.25 1.25 0 0 1 16 6.75a1.25 1.25 0 0 1 1.25-1.25M12 7a5 5 0 0 1 5 5a5 5 0 0 1-5 5a5 5 0 0 1-5-5a5 5 0 0 1 5-5m0 2a3 3 0 0 0-3 3a3 3 0 0 0 3 3a3 3 0 0 0 3-3a3 3 0 0 0-3-3Z"/></svg></a>
                </div>
                <div><a href=""><svg class="media-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path fill="currentColor" d="M22 12c0-5.52-4.48-10-10-10S2 6.48 2 12c0 4.84 3.44 8.87 8 9.8V15H8v-3h2V9.5C10 7.57 11.57 6 13.5 6H16v3h-2c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2h3v3h-3v6.95c5.05-.5 9-4.76 9-9.95z"/></svg></a>
                </div>
                <div><a href=""><svg class="media-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path fill="currentColor" d="M12.006 4.295c-2.67 0-5.338.784-7.645 2.353H0l1.963 2.135a5.997 5.997 0 0 0 4.04 10.43a5.976 5.976 0 0 0 4.075-1.6L12 19.705l1.922-2.09a5.972 5.972 0 0 0 4.072 1.598a6 6 0 0 0 6-5.998a5.982 5.982 0 0 0-1.957-4.432L24 6.648h-4.35a13.573 13.573 0 0 0-7.644-2.353zM12 6.255c1.531 0 3.063.303 4.504.903C13.943 8.138 12 10.43 12 13.1c0-2.671-1.942-4.962-4.504-5.942A11.72 11.72 0 0 1 12 6.256zM6.002 9.157a4.059 4.059 0 1 1 0 8.118a4.059 4.059 0 0 1 0-8.118zm11.992.002a4.057 4.057 0 1 1 .003 8.115a4.057 4.057 0 0 1-.003-8.115zm-11.992 1.93a2.128 2.128 0 0 0 0 4.256a2.128 2.128 0 0 0 0-4.256zm11.992 0a2.128 2.128 0 0 0 0 4.256a2.128 2.128 0 0 0 0-4.256z"/></svg></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="carta-content">
        <div class="carta-section">
            <div class="carta-opacity"></div>
            <div class="carta-img-container"><img class="carta-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/313700/pexels-photo-313700.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1600" alt=""></div>
            <div><h1 class="carta-title">NUESTRA CARTA</h1></div>
        </div>
        <!--STICKY NAV BAR ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <div class="sticky-container">
            <div class="carta-nav-bar">
                <div class="carta-items-container">
                    <div tabindex="0" class="carta-item">
                        RACIONES
                    </div>
                    <div class="carta-item">
                        ENSALADAS
                    </div>
                    <div class="carta-item">
                        CARNES
                    </div>
                    <div class="carta-item">
                        PESCADOS
                    </div>
                    <div class="carta-item">
                        ARROCES
                    </div>
                    <div class="carta-item">
                        VINOS
                    </div>
                    <div class="carta-item">
                        POSTRES
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="some-content">
            SOME CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

La barra de navegación es la que tiene cuadros naranjas, fondo blanco y borde superior e inferior. Alterna la opción de pantalla completa, no es responsive (todavía)

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

En este caso debes utilizar `position: fixed;` para fijarlo donde quieres, el
otro inconveniente es que la barra se mantendría en esa posición incluso sobreponiéndose al navbar, puedes resolver esto agregando una nueva clase `.sticky` e implementando un poco de JavaScript, ya que necesitas detectar cuándo el scroll pase por la barra de navegación, te dejo el código comentado.

```js
// obtenemos navbar y stickyContainer
const navbar = document.querySelector('.header__nav');
const stickyContainer = document.querySelector('.sticky-container');

// obtenemos el alto de navbar
const navbarHeight = navbar.offsetHeight;

// agregamos un evento de scroll al documento
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  // obtenemos la posición del scroll
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

  // si la posición del scroll es mayor o igual al alto de navbar, agrega la clase .sticky a stickyContainer
  if (scrollPosition >= navbarHeight) {
    stickyContainer.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    // de lo contrario elimina la clase .sticky
    stickyContainer.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #FF7F11;
  --secondary-color: #FCD757;
  --default-text: #f5f5f5;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  touch-action: none;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  touch-action: none;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h1,
p,
a,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Sawarabi Mincho', serif;
}

.menu {
  font-family: 'Sawarabi Mincho', serif;
}

.vl {
  border-left: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
  height: 30px;
}

.header__content-area {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 120px;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header__img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 114px;
}

.main-logo {
  height: 80px;
}

.menu__li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 25px;
  font-family: 'Sawarabi Mincho', serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu__li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.nav__list {
  padding: 0;
}

.menu__li>a {
  color: var(--default-text);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.menu__li>a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.header__social-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__social-nav>div {
  margin: 8px;
  height: 22px;
}

.header__social-nav>div>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--default-text);
}

.media-icon,
.mobile-media-icon {
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.media-icon:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  scale: 1.1;
}

.carta-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
}

.carta-opacity {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #0008;
}

.carta-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}

.carta-title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* STICKY NAV BAR ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.sticky-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carta-nav-bar {
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.carta-items-container {
  height: 75px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 120px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.carta-item {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.carta-item:hover {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carta-item:focus {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: var(--secondary-color);
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.some-content {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sticky.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300;400;900&family=Sawarabi+Mincho&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header__content-area">
      <div class="header__img-container"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5c25361496e76fbea2848f55/1553282628515-4T7SHD0BOHGWX7YVNQEM/JP_3_IN_logo.png" alt="" class="main-logo"></div>
      <nav class="header__nav">
        <ul class="nav__list">
          <li class="menu__li"><a href="index.html">INICIO</a></li>
          <li class="menu__li"><a href="carta.html">CARTA</a></li>
          <li class="menu__li"><a href="">MENÚS</a></li>
          <li class="menu__li"><a href="">CONTACTO</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav class="header__social-nav">
        <div><a href=""><svg class="media-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path fill="currentColor" d="M7.8 2h8.4C19.4 2 22 4.6 22 7.8v8.4a5.8 5.8 0 0 1-5.8 5.8H7.8C4.6 22 2 19.4 2 16.2V7.8A5.8 5.8 0 0 1 7.8 2m-.2 2A3.6 3.6 0 0 0 4 7.6v8.8C4 18.39 5.61 20 7.6 20h8.8a3.6 3.6 0 0 0 3.6-3.6V7.6C20 5.61 18.39 4 16.4 4H7.6m9.65 1.5a1.25 1.25 0 0 1 1.25 1.25A1.25 1.25 0 0 1 17.25 8A1.25 1.25 0 0 1 16 6.75a1.25 1.25 0 0 1 1.25-1.25M12 7a5 5 0 0 1 5 5a5 5 0 0 1-5 5a5 5 0 0 1-5-5a5 5 0 0 1 5-5m0 2a3 3 0 0 0-3 3a3 3 0 0 0 3 3a3 3 0 0 0 3-3a3 3 0 0 0-3-3Z"/></svg></a>
        </div>
        <div><a href=""><svg class="media-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path fill="currentColor" d="M22 12c0-5.52-4.48-10-10-10S2 6.48 2 12c0 4.84 3.44 8.87 8 9.8V15H8v-3h2V9.5C10 7.57 11.57 6 13.5 6H16v3h-2c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2h3v3h-3v6.95c5.05-.5 9-4.76 9-9.95z"/></svg></a>
        </div>
        <div><a href=""><svg class="media-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path fill="currentColor" d="M12.006 4.295c-2.67 0-5.338.784-7.645 2.353H0l1.963 2.135a5.997 5.997 0 0 0 4.04 10.43a5.976 5.976 0 0 0 4.075-1.6L12 19.705l1.922-2.09a5.972 5.972 0 0 0 4.072 1.598a6 6 0 0 0 6-5.998a5.982 5.982 0 0 0-1.957-4.432L24 6.648h-4.35a13.573 13.573 0 0 0-7.644-2.353zM12 6.255c1.531 0 3.063.303 4.504.903C13.943 8.138 12 10.43 12 13.1c0-2.671-1.942-4.962-4.504-5.942A11.72 11.72 0 0 1 12 6.256zM6.002 9.157a4.059 4.059 0 1 1 0 8.118a4.059 4.059 0 0 1 0-8.118zm11.992.002a4.057 4.057 0 1 1 .003 8.115a4.057 4.057 0 0 1-.003-8.115zm-11.992 1.93a2.128 2.128 0 0 0 0 4.256a2.128 2.128 0 0 0 0-4.256zm11.992 0a2.128 2.128 0 0 0 0 4.256a2.128 2.128 0 0 0 0-4.256z"/></svg></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="carta-content">
    <div class="carta-section">
      <div class="carta-opacity"></div>
      <div class="carta-img-container"><img class="carta-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/313700/pexels-photo-313700.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1600" alt=""></div>
      <div>
        <h1 class="carta-title">NUESTRA CARTA</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--STICKY NAV BAR ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
    <div class="sticky-container">
      <div class="carta-nav-bar">
        <div class="carta-items-container">
          <div tabindex="0" class="carta-item">
            RACIONES
          </div>
          <div class="carta-item">
            ENSALADAS
          </div>
          <div class="carta-item">
            CARNES
          </div>
          <div class="carta-item">
            PESCADOS
          </div>
          <div class="carta-item">
            ARROCES
          </div>
          <div class="carta-item">
            VINOS
          </div>
          <div class="carta-item">
            POSTRES
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="some-content">
      SOME CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```